# Web Audio Api writing oscilator with createBuffer()

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am trying to make a sine wave with createBuffer(). Like following code.

```
var TWOPI = Math.PI * 2;
var Sinewave = function(freq, amp, phase){
    var self  = this;   
    this.src;
    this.init = function(){

        var osc    = new self.Osc(phase);
        var buffer = ac.createBuffer(1, osc.samplerate, osc.samplerate);
        var buffering = buffer.getChannelData(0);

        for(i = 0; i < buffering.length; i++){
            buffering[i] = amp * this.sinetick(osc, freq);
        }

        this.src = ac.createBufferSource();
        this.src.buffer = buffer;
        this.src.loop = true;
        this.src.connect(contect.destination);
    } 

    this.Osc = function(_phase){
        this.samplerate = context.sampleRate;
        this.twopiovsr =  TWOPI/this.samplerate;
        this.curfreq    = 0;
        this.curphase   = _phase;
        this.incr       = 0.0;
    }


    this.sinetick = function(osc, freq){
        var val = Math.sin(osc.curphase);
        if(osc.curfreq != freq){
            osc.curfreq = freq;
            osc.incr = osc.twopiovsr * freq;
        }

        osc.curphase += osc.incr;
        if(osc.curphase >= TWOPI){
            osc.curphase -= TWOPI;
        }
        if(osc.curphase < 0.0){
            osc.curphase += TWOPI;
        }

        return val;
    }

    this.play = function(duration){
        this.src.start(0);
        this.src.stop(duration);
    }
}
```

This only contains function for sine wave but I've succeeded to implement other shapes as well.
Reason for this in the first place was to set phase offset, if there's a better option please give me a notice.

So, When I look at the output signal through oscilloscope they look like how they should be. However when I try to modulate frequency of a regular createOscillator node with the signal created by code above, output is not pretty. When regular createOscillators nodes fm themselves, waves on the oscilloscope changes horizontally, only frequencies, but with the signal generated with the code above gives changes in both horizontal and vertical giving clips

what could be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the problem was

```
var buffer = ac.createBuffer(1, osc.samplerate, osc.samplerate);
```

which should be

```
var buffer = ac.createBuffer(1, osc.samplerate/2, osc.samplerate);
```

Thanks guys